# What qualifies as a 'low-quality contribution' on Physics SE?

Tags: discussion, suspensions, quality

Something tells me this question is a duplicate of something.
I noticed somewhere that accounts can be suspended for 'low-quality contributions'. Could you point out what constitutes a 'low-quality' contribution and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspensions for low quality contributions are generally tied to a large number of downvoted and/or closed questions (relative to the total number of questions the user has asked, of course). So if you want to know this:

> Could you point out the questions that constitute a 'low-quality' contribution and why?

I would throw the question back at you: which of these questions would you downvote, and furthermore which of them would you expect the rest of the community to downvote as well? Which ones would you vote to close and expect others to vote to close?

When we suspend for low quality contributions, it is generally the community that has judged the contributions to be low quality, not (only) the moderators.

Comment: David Z, I was going to ask about this, and also about year-long suspensions, because [insert-here-the-user-who-shall-not-be-named] has been banned for a year for "low-quality contributions". 29 question asked, one of them at -1, about 17 at 0, the rest positive. So in this case it clearly wasn't the community who made the judgment.

Comment: @Mitchell actually you can't tell that because we also consider deleted questions when deciding on a suspension. Deleted questions are not visible in a user's profile, though (except to moderators). Also, this is why I said "generally." Because of the way the suspension system works, the low quality message is sometimes displayed even when the true reason is something a little different. As always, if you suspect a suspension is inappropriate you should contact the SE team, but bear in mind that there may be things going on which you're not aware of.

Comment: @DavidZ Could you expand on what the process is for those suspensions? Is there a specific public (or private) limit at which this happens? Does this happen automatically or must mods intervene? Is there an auto flagging mechanism?

Comment: @MitchellPorter: Adding to DavidZ's comment: Note as always, that publicly available information may involve only the tip of the iceberg. Particularly in cases where the offense seemingly (from a public perspective) does not match the penalty. There could be other issues as well in the suspension, such as, e.g., multiple accounts of low quality contributions, to name one example.

Comment: @Emilio Sometimes posts are automatically flagged, but suspensions are never automatic. There is not a specific quantitative threshold that triggers a suspension.

Comment: Suggestion to the answer (v1): In the first line replace the word 'downvoted' with 'downvoted posts' to make clear it applies to both answers and questions.