# Question of sending internet packets through time closed for "off topic"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen

[My question about sending internet packets through time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/753720/352388) was closed as "off-topic" as it was "non-mainstream-physics". This seems like mainstream physics to me, so it should fit on the site.

Comment: The comments on your question indicate that the Physics SE community (and the broader physics community) do not think that is mainstream physics.

Comment: Your question is also an open-ended hypothetical question [which is also considered off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: When you search the internet for “arxiv time portal”, do you find lots of papers on time portals?

Comment: Why do people downvote my question when it is about a question that is closed and want it to be reopened?

Comment: Because we think it was properly closed and should *not* be reopened.

Comment: Votes on meta sites are different from votes on the regular site. They indicate agreement/disagreement with the question (or answer). So, they indicate disagreement that your question is mainstream physics and should be reopened.

Comment: @JonCuster But do you think that should cause reputation changes?

Comment: @Lalala it doesn't.  Your reputation is tied to activity on the main site,  not on the meta site.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero but it seems to incur reputation on the main site...

Comment: @Lalala no it does not.  What does happen is that a meta post like yours will bring attention to your main question and may elicit up- or downvotes on the main site.

Comment: As an aside: deleting your post rather than edit-to-improve is not good.  The site has a (secret) algorithm to evaluate weak contributions, and the algorithm includes deleted questions in addition to downvotes of these questions.   See [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10737/36194) for some details.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero but deleting it is better than not deleting it and incurring downvotes. Anyways, it can’t be salvaged by any amount of editing.

Comment: @Lalala    FYI deleting does not eliminate the downvotes associated with the deleted question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero But it means it can't be downvoted even more

Comment: @Lalala A deletion is apparently worse than a downvote, although the details of the algorithm remain secret so people cannot “game” the said algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Your question about closure has already been answered under your physics question on the main site:

> If you look at the [first related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52386/44126) you'll see why time travel is basically considered impossible. On Physics SE we don't start with "let's pretend it is possible" because that's not physics, that's fantasy. What would happen is basically whatever the sci-fi writer wants to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is entirely unclear, because you don't say what "time travel" means.  And once you specify what you mean (e.g. motion along a closed timelike curve), the answer is probably obvious--- under your assumptions (whatever they are) what happens is exactly what you've assumed will happen.